# How to use AWS Secret Manager to keep CA signed SSL certificate to use it in applications

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, salesforce, aws-secrets-manager

Client wants to use AWS secrets manager to store as well as use the SSL certificates that they got from GoDaddy in their application. The application in this case is some Salesforce environment that we don't have access to or manage. They want Salesforce to call/ reference the SSL certificate stored in secrets manager rather than from somewhere else.

We have stored the SSL in secrets manager. In the screenshot that client shared for configuring the SSL in Salesforce side, we did not see any option to link secrets manager.

Is this even possible to achieve? Are there are any limitations?

Comment: That is strange. SSL certificate is usually a public key. Why store public key in a secret store?

Comment: The client wants to leverage everything from AWS only. What we are not able to get is even if we store all details of SSL in secrets manager, how to integrate it with Salesforce? Thats the biggest challenge